# How to access the component controller from browser console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console.log

In angular 1.x, when using `ng-controller`, one can access the controller instance from the browser console by inspecting an element and calling `angular.element($0).controller()`.

This doesn't work with components declared as:

```
angular.module('foo').component('bar', {
    controller: class {

    }  
});
```

Is there any other way to access the component's controller instance from the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the closest we get to access the component controller is:

`angular.element($0).scope().$ctrl`

Comment: For *component controller* this won't work because it uses isolate scope. Also, this won't work if a component has non-default controller identifier.

Comment: @estus This works exactly I expected. It allows me to find the controller for any element in the DOM. Yes, it won't work  for custom identifiers. But is simple enough to do the same as .controller() does.

Comment: This was my point. It won't work for any element. Because elements with inherited scope expose scopes as `.scope()`. And component elements themselves expose it as `.isolateScope()`.

Comment: But component's don't inherit scopes. As I said, this is the closest I could find, not a perfect replacement.

Answer (score 1):

As [the manual states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods),

> controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or
>   its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with the
>   ngController directive. If name is provided as camelCase directive
>   name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved (e.g.
>   'ngModel').

It is `angular.element($0).controller('bar')`.

For a component this may be narrowed down to

```
 angular.element($0).controller(
   $0.tagName.toLowerCase().replace(/-([a-z])/g, (_, c) => c.toUpperCase()))
 );
```

one-liner.

Comment: This doesn't actually do the same thing, as it requires you to know already what you're looking for. If you don't know the name of the directive, you need to look if up first which defeats the purpose.

Comment: It does what it does. `controller()` gets a controller for default directive (ngController). `controller(...)` gets a controller for other directives. There may be multiple directives per element and multiple controllers, thus getting a single arbitrary one doesn't make sense. You can check the name of required directive in DOM.

Comment: You can get a list of controllers (and other internal stuff) per element with `angular.element($0).data()`.

Comment: it seems .data() returns an empty object

Comment: What you're missing that is kind of implied is that I want to inspect *any* element, not a directive. That's what angular.element($0).controller() does. Your code works only for the tag that is the directive.

Comment: The question mentions component controller, which by definition belongs to component element. To access this controller in child elements use `inheritedData()` instead.